# What are the symmetries of standard model and its conservation laws?

Tags: particle-physics, symmetry, conservation-laws, standard-model

Is there like a list of symmetries in the standard model with associated conservation laws?

Comment: See, for example, the book "Introduction to Elementary Particles" by Griffith at chapter 4 "Symmetries"

Comment: There's a table "Symmetries of the Standard Model and associated conservation laws" here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_the_Standard_Model#Additional_symmetries_of_the_Standard_Model (for me this is the third google result for "symmetry standard model")

Comment: The Poincaré symmetries, and maybe Supersymmetry

Comment: @Andrew - I wish people would do this much basic research before asking questions here.

Answer (score 1):

First you have the continuous symmetry groups:

- the Poincaré group, which is all the isometries of space-time
- some gauge groups, depending on which interaction you're talking about: U(1) for QED, SU(3) for QCD and SU(2) for the weak force

Those above are the symmetry groups used to apply Noether's theorem when you're building theories.

Then you have discrete symmetries:

- C (charge, i.e. particle $\leftrightarrow$ anti-particle)
- P (parity)
- T (time)

The CPT theorem states that laws of physics are invariant under those three symmetries combined. However, they don't have to be under only one or two of them (see CP violations).

Finally you have minor conservation laws regarding particles (leptonic number conservation, and so on).

That's it, mostly. Others exist, the most famous probably being supersymmetry, but those mostly are speculations beyond the standard model.